# append an html tag right after $.ajax loads to another page

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit, onsubmit, ajaxform

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){


        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url:  $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json'

        }).done(function(data){ 

                    window.location.href = "manage_item.php";
                    $('body').append('<div>Item Added Successfully!</div>');


           });
});
```

I'm trying to load to another page with a successful alert when the ajax has added the data to my inventory. How can i solve this problem? What are the best practices in linking pages using $.ajax or are there any other alternatives aside from using $.ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best method would be pass a `get` variable along with the url after your ajax is successful some thing like this:

```
.done(function(data){ 

                    window.location.href = "manage_item.php?success=1";       
           });
```

and in your manage_item.php do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['success'] && $_GET['success'] == 1)){
echo "<div>Item Added Successfully!</div>"
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to not use $_GET? because i don't want to show the extra link. Can i do something like ajax inside .done() of another ajax?

Comment: one cheeky way would be use of document.referrer; in manage_item.php to know the previous url. If previous url === the page it ajax has come from then display success, But this is higly discouraged